# Installing phpDocumentor using PEAR

Tags: php, centos, pear, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

On the home page of http://www.phpdoc.org/, on http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.quickstart.pkg.html, and on https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2, instructions to install phpDocumentor are:

```
pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org
pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor
```

When I do so, I see that it is deprecated:

```
[root@desktop ~]# pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org
Adding Channel "pear.phpdoc.org" succeeded
Discovery of channel "pear.phpdoc.org" succeeded
[root@desktop ~]# pear install PhpDocumentor
WARNING: "pear/PhpDocumentor" is deprecated in favor of "phpdoc/phpdocumentor"
Did not download optional dependencies: pear/XML_Beautifier, use --alldeps to download automatically
pear/PhpDocumentor can optionally use package "pear/XML_Beautifier" (version >= 1.1)
downloading PhpDocumentor-1.4.4.tgz ...
Starting to download PhpDocumentor-1.4.4.tgz (1,534,088 bytes)
..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done: 1,534,088 bytes
install ok: channel://pear.php.net/PhpDocumentor-1.4.4
[root@desktop ~]# pear uninstall PhpDocumentor
uninstall ok: channel://pear.php.net/PhpDocumentor-1.4.4
```

According to http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/installation/using-pear.html#requirements, instructions are:

```
$ pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor-beta
```

Which is the preferred way to install phpDocumentor using PEAR?

Comment: And what happens when You run `pear install phpdoc/phpdocumentor` (mind the small **d**)???

Comment: I tried the beta version first, and it seemed to work.  Then tried your suggestion, and I got `[root@desktop ~]# pear install phpdoc/phpdocumentor
phpdoc/phpdocumentor is already installed and is the same as the released version 2.2.0
install failed
[root@desktop ~]#`

Comment: OK, so You have it installed. What's the problem then?

Comment: Sorry, I posted the question before attempting the beta version.  I didn't think I originally should have installed the beta version.  Feel free to post an answer either stating to use the beta version or a non-capitalized "d" and I will select it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> To install PEAR

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear 
sudo pear channel-update pear.php.net 
sudo pear upgrade-all
```

> To install php doc

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org 
sudo pear remote-list -c phpdoc 
sudo pear config-set data_dir /var/www 
sudo pear install --alldeps PhpDocumentor 
sudo pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor 
sudo mkdir /var/www/PhpDocumentor-output 
sudo chown www-data /var/www/PhpDocumentor-output
```

> To Install phpmd

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpmd.org 
sudo pear remote-list -c phpmd 
sudo pear install phpmd/PHP_PMD
```

> To install codesniffer

```
sudo pear install PHP_CodeSniffer
```

> To install phpdepend

```
sudo pear channel-discover pear.pdepend.org 
sudo pear remote-list -c pdepend 
sudo pear install pdepend/PHP_Depend
```

> To check all pear packages

```
sudo pear list all
```

> other useful commands

```
sudo pear upgrade-all
```

> to install phpunit test

```
sudo apt-get install phpunit
```

Comment: Great information, however, should be `pear install --alldeps  phpdoc/phpdocumentor`

Comment: Centos uses yum rather than apt-get. And you don't really need all that to install phpDocumentor. You just need the `pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org` and `pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor` lines - unless you really do want to change the default data directory, install optional dependencies, and set up output directory.

Answer (score 3):

I think the actual reason for that "deprecated" message you got was that you ran --

`pear install phpdocumentor`

without including the server alias of "phpdoc/" -- `pear install phpdoc/phpdocumentor`

No alias means the default alias of `pear/` got used, thus `pear install pear/phpdocumentor`

That's why it gave you the 1.x version, hosted from PEAR.  Notice that in your output:

```
[root@desktop ~]# pear install PhpDocumentor
WARNING: "pear/PhpDocumentor" is deprecated in favor of "phpdoc/phpdocumentor"
```

To get the 2.x version hosted at phpdoc.org, you must use the `phpdoc/` alias -- `pear install phpdoc/phpdocumentor`

The capital D doesn't matter, and the -beta doesn't matter.

Comment: You can read more about using channels (and their alias) at http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.channels.php

Answer (score 0):

I think regarding to the erro message the PhpDocumentor should be installed by:

```
pear install phpdoc/phpdocumentor
```

(mind the small **d**).

Comment: After posting my comment, I saw amarjit sngh's answer.  If it works, I will probably select that one.  Sorry again for the confusion.  Thank you

Comment: On my system it seems to be case-insensitive. The problem was that OP was installing from default channel.