# PhpDocumentor : How to choose templates?

Tags: php, templates, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

Recently I have met with PhpDocumentor. It looks like a good documentation tool. I want to use the 'responsive-twig' as template which comes with phpDocumentor.
I tried;

- --template="responsive-twig" in command line with phpdoc, It says 'ERROR: Unknown command-line option "--template" encountered, use phpdoc -h for help'
- Changed the 'name' attribute of the 'template' tag to 'responsive-twig' in /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/data/phpdoc.tpl.xml, default was 'clean'
- Changed the 'name' attribute of the 'template' tag to 'responsive-twig' in /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/phpdoc.dist.xml

However I cannot change the default template.

I have installed phpDocumentor via PEAR. I have three phpDocumentor directories. One in /var/www and two other('phpDocumentor' and 'PhpDocumentor') in /usr/share/php.

There is a 'responsive-twig' folder under /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/data/templates.

Please help!

Comment: Did you install phpDocumentor from the phpdoc channel or the default channel? What do you get if you type `phpdoc --version` at the command line?

Comment: I have installed phpDocumentor following the steps given in this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518713/installing-phpdocumentor-using-pear).
phpdoc --version gives that error:
ERROR: Unknown command-line option "--version" encountered, use phpdoc -h for help

Comment: What happens if you type `pear info phpdoc/phpDocumentor`? What version number is reported? If you type `phpdoc -h`, is `--template` or `--version` listed as an option?

Comment: It gives the details about phpdoc. For example, release date: 2014-02-26 21:00:50, Release version 2.3.1(stable). --template and --version are not listed

Comment: Very, very strange. I'm wondering if you have two different versions installed and they are interfering with each other. What happens if you type `pear info PhpDocumentor`, note the missing `phpdoc/`? If that returns anything, I'd try uninstalling both versions and then re-installing version 2.

Comment: I've uninstalled both versions and installed 2.3.1 using pear. Now `pear info phpDocumentor` gives nothing. Only `pear info phpdoc/phpDocumentor` works. However, this time `phpdoc` does not work. It outputs nothing to the terminal. It's like phpdoc starts, does nothing and exits. I can't even create documentation

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu. Can you write the steps to install phpdocumentor. I will uninstall everything and install again. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I also think both 1.x and 2.x were probably installed at the same time.  The error about --template looks like phpDocumentor 1.x, and that argument is only in 2.x. Info on 1.x is at manual.phpdoc.org, whereas info on 2.x is at phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/running-phpdocumentor.html.

Comment: So you did have two versions installed. And it looks like you uninstalled and reinstalled correctly. The steps would have been `pear uninstall phpdoc/phpDocumentor`, and `pear uninstall PhpDocumentor`, and then `pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor`. You shouldn't need to rediscover the phpdoc channel. I'm not sure why it's not working. Does `phpdoc -h` work? @ashnazg any ideas?

Comment: Being on Ubuntu should help. I would say v2 installed ok but is not in PATH, but bash would tell you that rather then print nothing. Does "which phpdoc" show anything? You could run "set -x" and then "phpdoc" to see what bash is actually doing.

Comment: Yes, I had both versions. I have uninstalled both of them. Then only installed version 2.3.1 .  This is the [terminal view](http://s27.postimg.org/gr95fo3gz/Screenshot_from_2014_04_01_18_38_20.png). I have followed these steps when installing phpdocumentor : `sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org` `sudo pear remote-list -c phpdoc` `sudo pear config-set data_dir /var/www` `sudo pear install --alldeps phpdoc/phpDocumentor` `sudo pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor` `sudo mkdir /var/www/PhpDocumentor-output` `sudo chown www-data /var/www/PhpDocumentor-output`

Comment: You don't need all that to install phpDocumentor as I mentioned in the comments of [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20519117/1862009). Did the install produce any error messages? @ashnazg Could changing the `data_dir` have any bearing on this issue? Why would there be no output from `phpdoc -h` AND no error from the shell?

Comment: I have reinstalled phpdoc. `phpdoc -h` gives that error: PHP Warning:  date_default_timezone_get(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone. in /usr/share/php/phpDocumentor/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 217

Comment: I have edited logger.php an now still no response :/

Comment: That PHP warning is about a new requirement PHP itself makes regarding the date.timezone setting in php.ini, so it's not coming from phpDocumentor.  If you edit date.timezone in your php.ini to a good value, or just put 'UTC', that error will go away.

Comment: Something to realize about PEAR - if you modify one of the *_dir settings, you must run forced updates of already installed packages to get that new setting to be applied. The settings are typically written into the source files at install time, so changing the setting after installation usually makes no difference to things already installed. Hence, run a forced update and those packages' source files will be updated using the new settings.

Answer (score 2):

FYI,
Succeed by follows:

```
yum install graphviz
pear install Image_GraphViz
rm -rf /tmp/phpdoc-twig-cache
phpdoc -d ./joomla-cms/libraries -t ./joomla-doc --template=responsive-twig
```

With latest phpDocumentor version 2.8.1
May help!